# how to upload an image to facebook from android

Tags: java, android, facebook, twitter, upload

I'm a new coder to android and I need to upload an image from my app to Facebook and/or twitter. I know that I need to use the Facebook SDK for Facebook, but I have no idea what to use for twitter, or what code to use once I've installed the SDK. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After you have facebook sdk setup a login button. That will do all the login work for you.
Then go inside facebook sdk and check demos they have there. you have one with the code for what you need.
You can also check the facebook dev for Graph API or Open Graph "path" you need to do what you want. Bty the way, Facebook sdk have a resquest class that handle all that for you. you just need to setup the graph path and the object you want to upload. You can find more on Graph API reference on facebook Dev site and how to to handle photos here: [Facebook Dev Pictures](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/)

Comment: Thank you so much, but do you know if my image needs to be saved somewhere on the device for it be posted to facebook, or if I can post it without saving it first?